# Some methods and modules do not work in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I am trying to calculate indices by Python API in VS Code area. The problem is that some methods and modules don't work in the Python area, especially in VSCode. Surprisingly, some methods work on Google Colab; however some methods don't work in Colab either.

Here's my code:

```
import eemont
import ee, geemap
import geemap.colormaps as cm

s2 = (ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
      .filterBounds(poi)
      .filterDate("2020-01-01","2021-01-01")
      .maskClouds()
      .scaleAndOffset())
```

for example in this code `filterBounds` and `filterDate` work but `maskCloud` does not work.
there are lots of methods that are missing in the packages.
how can fix this problem?

Comment: `maskClouds` and `scaleAndOffset` are eemont functions (e.g. https://eemont.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.0/guide/maskingClouds.html). Make sure your Python environment is set up to use eemont. I wonder if there are any conflicts between eemont and geemap?

Comment: @JustinBraaten thanks for your response. what do you mean by Python environment is set to use eemont. I have installed eemont, geemap, and ee. I have copied the exact script from its example on Github, but it seems some methods do not work. I hope you clarify your answer fro me. thanks

Comment: I suggest you submit an issue to the the eemont GitHub repo:
https://github.com/davemlz/eemont/issues

Comment: @JustinBraaten Thanks for your attention